# Unit testing in Flutter passing BuildContext

Tags: unit-testing, dart, flutter

I have a method in a Dart class, which accepts `BuildContext` parameter, as follows:

```
class MyClass {

  <return_type> myMethodName(BuildContext context, ...) {
        ...
        doSomething
        return something;
    }
}
```

I want to test that the method works as expected:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
...

void main() {
  MyClass sut;

  setUp(() {
    sut = MyClass();
  });

  test('me testing', () {

    var actual = sut.myMethodName(...);        

    expect(actual, something);
  });
}
```

Of course, it won't work, because the method `myMethodName` needs a parameter `BuildContext` type. This value is available throughout the application itself, but not sure where to get that from in my unit tests.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can actually mock the `BuildContext` so the test will run headless. I think it's better but might be not a solution that you are looking for.

`BuildContext` is an abstract class therefore it cannot be instantiated. Any abstract class can be mocked by creating implementations of that class. If I take your example then the code will look like this:

```
class MockBuildContext extends Mock implements BuildContext {}

void main() {
   MyClass sut;
   MockBuildContext _mockContext;

   setUp(() {
     sut = MyClass();
     _mockContext = MockBuildContext();
   });

   test('me testing', () {

   var actual = sut.myMethodName(_mockContext, ...);        

   expect(actual, something);
  });
}
```

(Note that this requires the Mockito package: https://pub.dev/packages/mockito).

Comment: It may be a nice-to-have to point people to the `mockito` package which can be found [here — pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito). That way, people who come across this answer would know that they are **first** expected to install the `mockito` package so they can reach the `Mock` class. Thank you :)

Comment: Returns `The argument type 'MockBuildContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'`

Answer (score 67):

One way is to use [`testWidgets`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/testWidgets.html) in combination with a [`Builder` widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html):

```
testWidgets('me testing', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    Builder(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        var actual = sut.myMethodName(context, ...);
        expect(actual, something);

        // The builder function must return a widget.
        return Placeholder();
      },
    ),
  );
});
```

Answer (score 46):

Here is a simple way to retrieve a BuildContext instance inside a test case:

```
testWidgets('showDialog', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Material(child: Container())));
  final BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(Container));

  final dialog = showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
      content: Text('shown by showDialog'),
    ),
  );

  // apply your tests to dialog or its contents here.
});
```

This was inspired by [Simple dialog control test](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/flutter/flutter/+/refs/tags/v0.0.13/packages/flutter/test/material/dialog_test.dart) from the Flutter test cases for the `showDialog()` function.

The whole "app" consist of a `Container` widget in a `MaterialApp` frame. The `BuildContext` instance is retrieved form by finding the `Element` instance related to the `Container`.

Comment: Best answer, as it allows me to tap a button and then expect after the UI has rebuilt as a result of the button tap. Using a builder doesn't allow me to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I am totally fine with 'surga' answer, but in some cases, it won't be good enough.
like when you want to use this `BuildContext` with `InhiretedWidget` for example: `Provider` or `MediaQuery`.

So I suggest using the `Mockito` default generator to generate the `BuildContext` class for you.

```
@GenerateMocks([BuildContext])
BuildContext _createContext(){
final context = MockBuildContext();
...
```

And add `build_runner` to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: any //use any version you want
```

Then run this command:

`flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

Now you can create a `context` object from the `MockBuildContext` class as it is created normally from the `MaterialApp`.

```
@GenerateMocks([BuildContext])
BuildContext _createContext(){
  final context = MockBuildContext();
  final mediaQuery = MediaQuery(
    data: MediaQueryData(),
    child: const SizedBox(),
  );
  when(context.widget).thenReturn(const SizedBox());
  when(context.findAncestorWidgetOfExactType()).thenReturn(mediaQuery);
  when(context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MediaQuery>())
      .thenReturn(mediaQuery);
  when(context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType())
      .thenReturn(InheritedElement(mediaQuery));
 
  return context;
}
```

**Note:** It's not required to add `when..thenReturn`'s for this Mock, it is depends on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs a context with localization info, this code can be useful. In my test case I need to test a message in three different idioms.

```
testWidgets('Calculation Provider context - getText02 tests',
  (WidgetTester tester) async {
await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => CalculationProvider.externalClock()),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        // If the current local is not listed, the first is picked
        //Locale('en'), // English
        Locale('pt'), // Portuguese
        //Locale('es'), // Spanish
      ],
      home: Container(),
    )));
final BuildContext context = tester.element(find.byType(Container));

final calculationProvider =
    Provider.of<CalculationProvider>(context, listen: false);

calculationProvider.now = DateTime(2023, 12, 23, 20, 50, 10);
calculationProvider.nextChristmas = DateTime(2023, 12, 25);
calculationProvider.nextChristmasMorning = DateTime(2023, 12, 25, 7);
calculationProvider.calculateRemainingTime();
expect(calculationProvider.getText02(context),
    '1 dia, 3 horas,\n9 minutos e\n50 segundos\n');
calculationProvider.now = DateTime(2023, 12, 23, 20, 50, 0);
calculationProvider.calculateRemainingTime();
expect(calculationProvider.getText02(context),
    '1 dia, 3 horas e\n10 minutos\n');
});
```